# Delete brackets in Live Template in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

How can I delete first and last bracket in Live Template in IDEA ?

```
('hello') -> 'hello'
```

Comment: [Unwrap](https://i.imgur.com/PnIl9o5.png)?

Comment: Yes, I need to unwrap it in Live Template

Comment: How does the template look like and where/how do you plan to invoke it?

Comment: The reverse template looks like this 
($selection$)$end$

You are right that I need the unwrap hotkey, but it works only in Java classes. I want to make it working in other files too, e.g., in R scripts..

Comment: Live templates expand specific text to something different, you can't use it for unwrapping. If Unwrap doesn't work in some language, you should ask the language plug-in developers to support it. For the R language request can be [submitted here](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/r4intellij/issues).

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to make unwrapping Live Template because it just expands the code given.